# How can I bring specific data on a query using MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I'm new using Mongo, and I'm doing a little project, the thing is this, this is one document in my collection as an example:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("649dbc85ff38d4464e5c0ee5"),
  user: '649dbc85ff38d4464e5c0ee2',
  friend: [
        {
         id: '649dbc81ff38d4464e5c0edd',
         name: 'paco'
        },
       {
         id: '649dbc63ff38d4464e5c0ed8',
         name: 'angel'
       }
   ]
}
```

As you can see my document have a field call `friends` is an object that contains an id and a name so, I want to bring id and name of the field `friend` if the name is 'x' (any name) of the user 'x'(any user), so if I do that my query this must bring this if I search the user `649dbc85ff38d4464e5c0ee2` and the name `paco` in the friend array:

```
{
  id: '649dbc81ff38d4464e5c0edd',
  name: 'paco'
}
```

i try with this query

```
db.friends.find(
  {user:"649dbc85ff38d4464e5c0ee2", friend: {"name":"paco"}}
)
```

and works at half because in fact he founds the information, but it returns it like 2 consults I mean like this

[image]

And I need it like the one above. Thank you for read this and thanks if your trying

Comment: Use $elemMatch https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this query:

```
db.friends.find(
  { user: "649dbc85ff38d4464e5c0ee2", "friend.name": "paco" },
  { "friend.id": 1, "friend.name": 1, _id: 0 }
);
```

To learn more, see https://sparkbyexamples.com/mongodb/query-nested-objects-in-mongodb/